# Issue with Antlr Stringtemplate V4 ArrayList iteration

Tags: arraylist, loops, stringtemplate

heres my test in java

```
public class person
{
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
}
```

In my function I create a number of person objects
and add it into an list

```
ArrayList<person> arr = new ArrayList<person>()
arr.add(person1);
arr.add(person2); etc etc
```

in the string template group file I have got

```
test(arr) ::= <<
 <table>
 $arr: {a|
 <tr><td>$a.name$</td><td>$a.age$</td></tr>
 }$
 </table>
>>
```

this is called from my list template

```
list (arr) ::= <<

$test(arr)$

... and other page details etc
>>
```

in version4 for I get template not found message with some stack trace as follows

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.RewriteRuleTokenStream.nextNode(RewriteRuleTokenStream.java:58)
at org.stringtemplate.v4.compiler.STParser.subtemplate(STParser.java:1563)
at org.stringtemplate.v4.compiler.STParser.mapTemplateRef(STParser.java:3692)
```

but I can list an array as follows and it prints the object representation in string format
(also I can use a map - ie key value pairs works ok too)

in string template

```
test(arr) :: =<<
 <p>
 $arr; seperator="</br>"$
 </p>
>>
```

how do we iterate list of object to print field values using string template grop in V4
am I using it in a wrong format/syntax?

any help/points would be greateful

note: we set $ as delimiter using new STGroupString("", templateGroup, '$', '$');

Comment: kind of working now (not tested everything. tested with a string array with curly brackets )
seems its not a bug in stringtemplate .. its antlr - not sure where is this problem come from
we are using antlr 3.4..runtime.
but when me rolled back to the version 3.2 it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the terminating $ on your expression: $a.age should be $a.age$

Comment: Thanks, I missed a $ when I typed my question into stackoverflow. edited it now. still cant load the template (see edited question)